# How to create multiple listeners for Classic Load Balancer using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I was wondering if I can add multiple listener rules for Classic Load Balancer with a CloudFormation template?

I tried adding listener rules but it was not taking them and I was told that we can not add multiple rules with a CloudFormation template.

AWS doc says we can use like below but can iIadd multiple listeners here?

```
{
  "InstancePort" : String,
  "InstanceProtocol" : String,
  "LoadBalancerPort" : String,
  "PolicyNames" :  [ String, ... ],
  "Protocol" : String,
  "SSLCertificateId" : String
}
```

Comment: You should include the resource type in your example. It's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from [cloud-formation-templates/load-balancers.template at master · markitx/cloud-formation-templates](https://github.com/markitx/cloud-formation-templates/blob/master/load-balancers.template):

```
    "Listeners" : 
      [ {
        "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
        "InstancePort" : "80",
        "Protocol" : "HTTP"
      },
      {
        "LoadBalancerPort": "443",
        "InstancePort" : "8080",
        "Protocol" : "HTTPS",
        "PolicyNames" : [ "HTTPSCookieStickinessPolicy" ],
        "SSLCertificateId" : "TODO: ARN for your SSL certificate here or remote HTTPS support"
      } ],
```